# how to I use functions in vba from my personal macro workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function in my personal workbook:

```
Public Function Get_Rows_Generic_personal(sheet_name As String) As Long
    Get_Rows_Generic = Worksheets(sheet_name).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

How do I call it from a module in another project?

[This thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/580556-functions-personal-macro-workbook.html) was supposed to have the answer but the link is dead.

Comment: You can use `application.run` or you can set a reference to the VBA project of your personal macro workbook, but you'll need to change the name of the project from the default 'VBAProject' first. Once you have a reference set, you can call the function directly.

Comment: I don't know how to use `application.run`.  I found this example (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm), but don't understand how to apply it here.  Can you pls answer with the proper syntax?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices really:

1. You can use `Application.Run`; or
2. You can set a reference to the VBA project of your personal macro workbook ( but you'll need to change the name of the project from the default 'VBAProject' first). Once you have a reference set, you can call the function directly

To use `Application.Run` you pass the workbook and routine name as the first argument, then any arguments required by that routine as additional arguments to `Run`. If the routine name is the same as its parent module, or you have more than one routine in the workbook with the same name, you need to supply the module name too, and if the workbook name contains spaces, you need to enclose it in single quotes. So the basic syntax is either:

```
Application.Run "'workbook name.xlsm'!routine_name", parameter1
```

or:

```
Application.Run "'workbook name.xlsm'!module_name.routine_name", parameter1
```

For example:

```
dim lCounter as long
lCounter = Application.Run("'Personal.xlsb'!Get_Rows_Generic_personal", "some sheet")
```